# Вопрос по методу .call()

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код

```
var abc = [1, 55, 399, 100].reduce(function(acc, el) {
    console.log('el= ' + el);
    acc += el;
    console.log('acc= ' + acc);
    return acc;
}, 0);
console.log('abc=' + abc);
 // el= 1
 // acc= 1
 // el= 55
 // acc= 56
 // el= 399
 // acc= 455
 // el= 100
 // acc= 555
 // abc=555
```

Не пойму как получить доступ к каждому элементу массива [1, 55, 399, 100] при вызове call() метода и подстановке аргумента допустим +10

```
var abc = [1, 55, 399, 100].reduce.call(каждый_элемент_плюс_десять,function(acc, el) {}

// или по другому в аргументе call должно быть такое
[1, 55, 399, 100].forEach( function(element, index) {
    console.log(element+10);
    return element+10;
});
```

Возможно ли такое сделать без создания предварительного массива для увеличения его значений, а затем подстановки в reduce.call()?

Без предварительного формирования массива имеется в виду такого:

```js
var b = [1, 55, 399, 100];
var d = [];
b.forEach( function(element, i) {
 d[i] = element+10;
});

document.writeln(d +'<br>');

var abc = b.reduce.call(d, function(acc, el) {
 acc += el;
 return acc;
}, 0);
document.writeln('abc=' + abc);
```

Comment: первый параметр `call` - это контекст - фактически для функции `reduce` - это должен быть массив либо ArrayLike объект. Поэтому не совсем понятно, что же все-таки пытаешься сделать

Comment: @Grundy возможно ли получить контекст от массива?

Comment: вот она :) путаница в терминологии. Судя по коду, тут не нужен `call` вообще, достаточно `return acc+el+10`

Comment: ну и нельзя _получить контекст от чего-либо_

Comment: @Grundy пожалуй тут важно было не увеличение элемента массива на 10, а скорее преобразование его на лету, может +10, а может и другое действие.

Comment: @Grundy это изучение метода call(), поэтому он нужен тут в любом случае, возможно задача подобрана была не совсем подходящая.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38299/discussion-between-grundy-and-jean-claude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как работает `call`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
В данном случае `call` применяется к `reduce`, а Вы хотите добавить аргумент в `callback`, верно? Не выйдет.
`call` лишь меняет `this` для `reduce` (а этого не нужно делать, иначе ошибка будет) и может добавить каррирование для **`reduce`**, не к `callback`.
Обработайте массив логикой и потом сведите его к одному числу.

```js
let array    = [1, 55, 399, 100],
    newArray = array.map(e => e += 10).reduce((a, e) => {a += e; return a;});

document.writeln('Before: ' + array + '<br />');
document.writeln('After: &nbsp;&nbsp;' + newArray);
```

Comment: _а этого не нужно делать, иначе ошибка будет_? почему же будет ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy Используется Сила, т. е. `this` внутри. https://jsfiddle.net/pqLj23eb/1/ 
Ошибка не в JS, а в ожидаемом поведении. Хотя можно и ошибку интерпретатора выбить, если будет некорректный `this`.

Comment: В примере по ссылке вполне себе call меняет this и ошибки нет. Ну и каррирование call не может добавлять, потому что возвращает не функцию

Comment: @Grundy Нет ошибки говоришь... http://i.stack.imgur.com/sCjlo.png
Про каррирование согласен, тут подмена идёт только на месте, `Function.prototype.bind` нужен для полноценного каррирования.

Comment: Ну так большинство операций с null вернут ошибку. к тому же в другом случае - нормально :)

Comment: @Grundy Вот упёртый :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/kCQdw.png - вот с функцией ошибка. Да и правильно оно: передал аргументы не того типа - лови ошибку. Если `this` будет указывать на не массив (или он будет пуст), то `reduce` ничего не сможет сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, не массив и все работает :) `[].reduce.call({0:1,5:2,length:6}, function(a,b){return a+b;})`, а вот с пустым массивом: `[].reduce.call([], function(a,b){return a+b;},0)` и тоже работает :)

Comment: кстати, в `map` нет смысла использовать `+=` так как элемент исходного массива все равно не поменяется поэтому достаточно обычного `+`, то же касается и `reduce`, в данном случае можно просто сумму возвращать

Comment: @Grundy, хитрец, однако :) Массивоподобный объект и с переданным первым элементом... А  по присвоению согласен, просто чуть нагляднее вышло, не себе же пишу, а помощь оказал, правда, видимо, не нужную, ибо автор забил.

Comment: _Массивоподобный объект и с переданным первым элементом_ так в ответе просто _этого не нужно делать, иначе ошибка будет_ - а выше примеры, что ошибки нет. Фактически ответ, мягко говоря - не полон

Comment: @Grundy Запутался уже :) Одно ясно - в данном контексте ответ верный. И, главное, рабочий.

Comment: @Other не забил, на тот момент это было не совсем то, что хотел услышать. В чате полялякал с грунди.

Comment: @Jean-Claude В чём ненужную? Хотел бы исправится.